# Is it safe to pass setInterval or setTimeout a fractional delay?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, settimeout, setinterval

I know that the difference would currently be negligible due to inaccurate browser timers, but for the sake of knowledge if nothing else: is there any browser that supports setInterval and setTimeout, but requires that they be passed an integer value as a delay?

Or, rephrased with examples, is this:

```
setInterval(animate,50/3);
```

as cross-browser compatible as this?

```
setInterval(animate,17);
```

Comment: The way it's defined, the second argument is the "number of miliseconds". Now, if that number should be natural is not defined...

Comment: @ŠimeVidas It's perfectly defined. See the DOM specification ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is perfectly safe.

(As RobG points out, I haven't provide a reference to the DOM/JS bridge rules themselves and he urges caution. FWIW, I believe -- but have no reference to conclusively state -- that `ToInteger` *is* part of the interface bridge. Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NT3nh/) showing the timeout being passed as a string, a float, and an integral (same type as float in JS) which works fine in FF8 and IE9. Feedback welcome.)

This is because [*the DOM interface only accepts integers*](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/timers.html#timers) for the delay in `setTimeout/setInterval` -- yup, these are defined in the DOM, not in ECMAScript. The delay value is appropriately converted to an integral value first (and in this aspect the [JS-internal] `ToInteger` function is invoked *which performs a truncation**).

However, the example numbers will actually yield *slightly different results* (although it might not be noticable) :-)

This is because, `50/3` (`16.66andsomemore` -> `16`) and `17` *specify different timeouts*.

Happy coding.

---

*`ToInteger` is defined as `sign(number) * floor(abs(number))`, excluding special cases. See Section 9.4 of the 5th Edition ECMAScript specification.

Comment: Ok, so this spec is describing the C (or something else not javascript) implementation, right? So the truncation occurs outside of the javascript environment?

Comment: @skier88 Technically the DOM implementation doesn't *have* to be in C -- although I suspect it is in most cases -- but it does restrict the value to an integral "long". There is a[n inaccessible to user] portion of the JS engine which knows how to "talk to the DOM" which does the conversions to/from the DOM. The link posted just covers the *interface* contracts. The `ToInteger` function is an internal function defined in ECMAScript, and I believe -- but I could be wrong -- that this (or an equivalent) is used in the integral conversion.

Comment: Yeah, I know the language can vary, it just helps me to think of an example programming language to visualize what level code is being executed at. Thanks for the response - I probably should have downloaded the specification a long time ago.

Comment: I wouldn't call it "perfectly safe". The HTML5 spec (which is not a standard) says "optional long timeout", so give it an integer and don't depend on someone else doing error correction.

Comment: @RobG I still think it's perfectly safe -- e.g. pass it a string and it won't blow up, but will be converted through `ToInteger` as well -- however, as I *can't find a reference* as to the actual DOM/JS bridge, I can't refute that... Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NT3nh/)

Comment: @pst—no doubt it works fine in all the browsers you've tested. I remember some time ago setting a style property that wanted an integer using a float - most browsers just truncated the float, others threw an error. So I learned it's much better to fix possible errors first and to not rely on the vagaries of browser error correction doing it for me.

Answer (score 5):

Javascript makes no real distinction between floating point numbers and integers, and are the same data type under the hood.  `1` and `1.0` are bit for bit identical in memory.

Therefore yes, you can pass a fractional value without any real issues.  It's perfectly valid JavaScript.  And even if it did require an integer, it's more likely it would simply and silently round it down for you.

**But don't expect it to be accurate!**  A time of `0.1`, `1` or even `4.87` will all probably fire at very close to the same time due to the low granularity of the callback scheduling.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't thinking data types for some reason. And good point about the granulatiry - IIRC, it's actually often as bad as 15ms. My concern is really only for the (probably imperceptible) drift of a long-running interval.

Comment: The drift is real and it was a problem I recently ran into with using it to time music beats.  And it sucks.  This was my solution: http://alexwayne.tumblr.com/post/13744997785/accurateinterval Or skip the prose and get my raw code here: https://gist.github.com/1d99b3cd81d610ac7351

Comment: The fact that `1` and `1.0` represent the same Number value in the JavaScript language is not relevant here. The question is about the behavior of the `setTimeout` function. Note that this function is not part of the JavaScript language. It is a browser function which is specified in the HTML standard. As far as I can tell, if a non-natural number is provided as the second argument (like `1.23`), the behavior is undefined, which means that it's up to the browsers to implement a behavior for this.

Comment: All true.  But in practice, it either rounds it to an integer, or it really uses it as fractional.  Either way you don't really know.  And Either way the answer to `Is it safe to pass setInterval or setTimeout a fractional delay?` is a pretty unambiguous "yes its fine".

Comment: Thanks for the code - it's not exactly relevant to my current application, but interesting nonetheless. So you actually found better results with timeouts and repeatedly getting timestamps than intervals? Also, it sounds like you were right, but pst pointed out that it is actually truncated outside of javascript. So it would be a (slightly) better idea to just write the number that will be used.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that timeout and interval both use the same scheduling.  But using a timeout allows you customize how much time until the next call.  This allows you to compensate for any drift on the next iteration caused by the callback executing a millisecond or two late.

Comment: Yes, but I was under the impression that setInterval calls were scheduled at a set interval, regardless of how long it takes the code to run (unless it takes longer than the interval). It seems you found this not to be the case? Or, maybe your function ran longer than your interval?

Comment: Drift in `setInterval` was real for me. It seems to be implemented in such a way that `setInterval(fn, 1000)` means: Schedule a callback to `fn` in 1000ms.  When that is callback is triggered, schedule another callback in another 1000ms from the current time.  So if the first callback actually runs 1ms or 2ms late (which happens a lot), then you have just lost 2ms permanently.  My implementation detects that drift and schedules the next callback at `1000ms - 2ms`, making up for the fact the callback ran a little late.

Comment: Oh, wow, I didn't realize that - I thought all the callbacks were scheduled relative to the invocation time. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that the second parameter would be evaluated as an expression and as long as it returns a number it will work. It seems to work in chrome. Just make sure you don't divide by zero!

Answer (score 0):

These functions expect milliseconds.  I doubt you could expect any accuracy greater than 10ms, and browsers [enforce timer restrictions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout#Minimum_delay_and_timeout_nesting).

Firefox doesn't mind decimal values.  You [can test](http://jsfiddle.net/5V8pS/) in any other browsers you're curious about.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As above, I'm not concerned with accurate timing so much as drift (imperceptible though it may be).

Answer (score 0):

It depends, depends on whether argument `delay` is converted to integer, whether cumulative-delay<sup>[^1]</sup> strategy is used, depends on whether you are using a battery-powered device and power saving mode is on.

Test  `setInterval` with 1000/15~=66.6667 delay, 60s duration, keep page visible all the time (without switching to background, without screen off), with the following browsers:

- Windows Chrome 108
- Android Chrome 107
- iOS Safari 16.0
- Windows Firefox 107
- Android Firefox 108 Beta

see CodePen [setInterval actual interval test](https://codepen.io/fuweichin/pen/PoayPbm)

Actual average interval tick of `setInterval`

| occasion \ platform | Windows Chrome | Android Chrome | macOS Safari | iOS Safari | Windows Firefox | Android Firefox |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| page visible | 66.01 | 66.01 |  | 66.69 | 78.45 | 66.67 |
| page visible (battery power saving mode) | 66.01 | 66.01 |  | 89.76 | 78.36 | 66.68 |
| page hidden |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| page hidden (battery power saving mode) |  |  |  |  |  |  |

According to the test result above, what I can tell is:

Chrome's setInterval will `floor()` argument delay, but it use self-calibration<sup>[^2]</sup> strategy to keep ticks in time, currently ignores Batter Saver Mode.

Safari's setInterval depends on state of Low Power Mode, it supports fractional delay and use self-calibration strategy to keep ticks in time, but if Low Power Mode is on then cumulative-delay effect happens such that a fractional delay just doesn't help.

Windows Firefox's setInterval uses cumulative-delay strategy，while Android Firefox's setInterval uses self-calibration strategy.

Footnote:

<sup>[^1]</sup>: cumulative-delay means average tick interval will be obviously larger than argument `delay`.

<sup>[^2]</sup>: self-calibration means average tick interval can be very close to argument `delay`.