# alternative of setTimeout(code,millisec) api

Tags: javascript, performance, timer

Is there any alternative of `setTimeout(callback,sleep_time_in_millisec)` api in js where I can use sleep time in `microsec` or `nanosec` value;

or `setTimeout(callback,sleep_time_in_millisec)` itself is that much accurate to handle float value in sleep_time_in_millisec?

Comment: The best some browsers will do is to respond in about 15ms increments, so setting a value in micro or nanoseconds is pointless. Also, there really isn't any standard for setTimeout (it's in [HTML5](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/timers.html#timers), but really only to document current behaviour) so not particularly reliable if precision or accuracy are required.

Comment: @RobG, Thanks for reply, may be minimum value is 15 ms or 10 ms; but I want to make it sleep for 30.5589 millisec ; not 30 millisec or 31 millisec...

Comment: Note I wrote **about 15ms increments**, not *minimum value*, so what you want to do is impossible with common javascript implementations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such API and `setTimeout` will not work with float values. In fact, `setTimeout` offers no guarantee that your callback will be invoked when the designated time has passed but only when *at least as much* as the designated time has passed (it could invoke the callback after one hour and that would still be OK according to the API specification).

See also [What is minimum millisecond value of setTimeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9647215/50079)

If you are writing time-critical code, JavaScript is the wrong language to do it in.

Comment: Thanks for reply, yes my code is time-critical; and I am writing it for browser; if javascript is not good language for my project, then what is your suggestion ? which language should I prefer?

Comment: @Swarnendu: Well, it would take a native-based technology (ActiveX, Java applet, or Chrome [Native Client](https://developers.google.com/native-client/)). Except for Java these are of course not cross-browser. But my rule of thumb suggestion would be "just don't try to do it in the browser".

Comment: Well that is not a language limitation, `setTimeout` is not even part of the language. If there is need for such facilities in the browser, then you should request them/make your case. Slightly related is the addition of [high resolution time API](http://www.w3.org/TR/hr-time/).

Answer (score 1):

Have you try with setinterval(callback,sleep_time_in_millisec) and clearinterval in javascript

Comment: does `setInterval` handles `float value`  in sleep_time_in_millisec?

Comment: Can you pls refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8468790/is-it-safe-to-pass-setinterval-or-settimeout-a-fractional-delay. I think its may helpful for you.